# Scrapy DNS Lookup Error

Tags: python, dns, scrapy

When I try to crawl the following URL I get a DNS Lookup error. URL: http://extremecouponprofessors.net/2012/03/anyone-get-cash-in-the-mail-today-im-not-kidding-i-got-cash-lol/

Error:

```
DNS lookup failed: address 'http://extremecouponprofessors.net/2012/03/anyone-get-cash-in-the-mail-today-im-not-kidding-i-got-cash-lol/' not found: timeout error.
```

When accessing w/ scrapy shell I get the same error

```
scrapy shell "http://extremecouponprofessors.net/2012/03/anyone-get-cash-in-the-mail-today-im-not-kidding-i-got-cash-lol/"
```

Scrapy Shell Error:

```
elif failure.check(DNSLookupError): SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

dig extremecouponprofessors.net:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> extremecouponprofessors.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9017
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0    

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;extremecouponprofessors.net.   IN  A   

;; ANSWER SECTION:
extremecouponprofessors.net. 4563 IN    A   198.136.50.148  

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.101.7#53(192.168.101.7)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 18 16:12:00 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

Comment: Assuming the host OS is Linux, what is the output of `dig extremecouponprofessors.net` from the host where you are running your crawler? If this is not Linux, use the DNS resolver tool appropriate for that OS.

Comment: @SashaPachev Ran dig -- it resolves.

Comment: I got a 200 response with your scrapy command pasted verbatum into the terminal. Try `strace -f -o /tmp/strace.out -s 4096 scrapy shell "scrapy shell "http://extremecouponprofessors.net/2012/03/anyone-get-cash-in-the-mail-today-im-not-kidding-i-got-cash-lol/"`, then make '/tmp/strace.out' available somewhere.

Comment: @SashaPachev sorry - what is the OSX equivalent to strace -- dtrace?